# Connect to snowflake via SSO login (external browser) using DBeaver

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

My SNOWFLAKE database is SSO login enabled and the SSO connectivity works perfectly fine when I connect through my chrome browser.

When I try to connect to SNOWFLAKE database using DBeaver (external browser) I get the below error .
[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

NOTE : I can confirm that I am able to see the identity verification (through explorer browser) page and the identity has also been verified. I feel the issue happens when the explorer browser confirms the identity verification back to DBeaver.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: make sure you don't have any typos in the DBeaver connection information.  The username has to match your SSO username.

Comment: Yes .The SSO username and user name provided in dBeaver are the same.

Comment: Enable [JDBC](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#JDBC) log and provide maybe a snippet of the log when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The above error is a generic message and could be seen due to misconfigurations either at the identity provider end or at the service provider end.
It is recommended to verify the configurations for your identity provider and make sure all the steps are performed correctly.

Below could be the common reasons for this error, However, there might be other improper configs as well which could lead to a similar error message.

a. Mismatch in user configuration details at Idp(Identity provider) and Snowflake.

b. SSO certificates are incorrect.

Solution

a. Username configured at the Identity provider end should match with the login_name at snowflake end for that user. For instance, If the SAML response shows NameID as abc@xyz.com. Then login_name configured at Snowflake end should be same as abc@xyz.com

SAML response snippet:

abc@xyz.com

Set the login_name same as the NameID configured at the identity provider side.

alter user  set login_name='abc@xyz.com';

b. SSO certificate configured at Snowflake end should match with the certificate configured at the identity provider end.

Note:

1. The certificate value contains a number of new lines. Remove the new lines, forming a certificate value with a single line.
2. If the above suggestions did not help then please check the error codes for the failed login attempt in Snowflake  Information Schema using the below query. And check the reason for that error code here. The below query retrieve up to 100 login events of every user your current role is allowed to monitor in the last hour and you can modify it appropriately.

select * from table(information_schema.login_history(dateadd('hours',-1,current_timestamp()),current_timestamp())) order by event_time